# Converting object dtype to int, type error continues to show after casting also

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
bow_df['runs'].astype(int)
bow_df['runs'] > 25
```

Error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Even after converting the dtype im getting the same type error

want to perform few aggregate functions on runs column

Comment: is bow_df['runs'] columns contains only numbers?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not re-assigning the Series to the DataFrame.
Try:

```py
bow_df['runs'] = bow_df['runs'].astype(int)
bow_df['runs'] > 25
```

The statement you use at the moment has no effect. It only creates a copy of the Series, casted to `int`, but *it doesn't change the column itself*.